# Unable to align tooltip properly with multiple tooltip message

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -15px;
    left: 110%;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 100%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Right Tooltip w/ Left Arrow</h2>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <ul class="tooltiptext">
   <li>Tooltip text 1</li>
   <li>Tooltip text 2</li>
   <li>Tooltip text 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Works perfectly with one Tooltip message, but not with multiple message.
It should always be vertically center regardless the no of tooltip messages.
Feel free to ask question if anyone didn't understand the scenario.

Comment: Try replacing `top` property in `.tooltiptext` with `transform: translateY(-55%);` Looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using margin values to adjust / place the toopltip.

Use  `top:50%` and a `transform` to vertically center by dragging it back up 50% of its own height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 120%;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 100%;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <ul class="tooltiptext">
    <li>Tooltip text 1</li>
    <li>Tooltip text 2</li>
    <li>Tooltip text 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <ul class="tooltiptext">
    <li>Tooltip text 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, how to dynamically reorient the tooltip(right or left). For example, the tooltip should display on the left side when possible, otherwise on the right.

Comment: For that you will need javascript.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't. But I'm sure you could find it on SO.